# CSV append overwrites everything but column headers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to fetch online reviews (multiple pages), extract parts of each review (title, user, text,...) and write that information to a csv file. Yeah those questions have been asked multiple times, but i couldn't find the one that solves my issue below:

First I create & prepare the column headers of the csv file at the beginning:

```
with open('review-raw-data.csv', 'wb') as output:
    fieldnames = ['title', 'text', 'starRating', 'helpfulScore', 'date', 'user', 'id', 'url']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, restval='unknown',                       extrasaction='ignore')
```

Which works fine. Later I'm trying to append the extracted information to that csv file:

```
def extract(data):
    with open('review-raw-data.csv', 'ab') as output:
        fieldnames = ['title', 'text', 'starRating', 'helpfulScore', 'date', 'user', 'id', 'url']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(output, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, restval='unknown', extrasaction='ignore')

        for review in data:
            # extraction happening...
            reviewobj = Review(title, text, helpfulscore, rating, date, user, reviewid, url)

            writer.writerow({'title': reviewobj.title, 'text': reviewobj.text, 'starRating': reviewobj.rating,
                         'helpfulScore': reviewobj.helpfulscore, 'date': reviewobj.date, 'user': reviewobj.user,
                         'id': reviewobj.reviewid, 'url': reviewobj.url})
```

This function gets called after each review-page has been received. 
So this probably isn't the smartest/easiest way to do it, but it works. 
The problem is, that the appending part isn't working as expected when calling this code for the 2nd, 3rd, ... time, because **all the rows appended in previous iterations get overwritten. The column headers remain in place.**

Example of **what i wanted**: (columns separated by ',')

```
title, user, id
title1, user1, id1
title2, user2, id2
title3, user3, id3
```

Example of **what i get** after 2nd iteration:

```
title, user, id
title2, user2, id2  # row 1 is missing...
```

Example of **what i get** after 3rd iteration:

```
title, user, id
title3, user3, id3  # rows 1 & 2 are missing...
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: It sure sounds like you're running the code you show at the top where you open the file in `w` mode (truncating its existing contents, if any). Are you sure that's only being called once?

Comment: Could you not just pass `writer` as a parameter to `extract()` and keep the file open?

Comment: @MartinEvans that would be better but I don't think it would solve the problem - with the file opened in "ab" mode, the writer will _not_ overwrite existing content (cf mcve in my answer).

Comment: @Blckknght oh dear lord why -.- I somehow messed up badly and called the code (creating csv & preparing column headers) each time. Don't ask me how or why ... :D Even without the whole code you pointed me in the right direction - +1 for that. Don't know if you want to add your comment as an answer, so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to tell exactly what goes wrong without the whole code - and without knowing how you call that code -, but you're obviously calling the "create & prepare the column headers" part of the code more than once, because the following works as expected:

```
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ cat appcsv.py
import csv

with open('review-raw-data.csv', 'wb') as output:
    fieldnames = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, restval='unknown', extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()


def extract(data):
    with open('review-raw-data.csv', 'ab') as output:
        fieldnames = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(output, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, restval='unknown', extrasaction='ignore')
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(dict(zip(fieldnames, row)))


dataset = [
    [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)],
    [(5, 6, 7),]
    ]

for data in dataset:
    extract(data)


bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ python appcsv.py
bruno@bigb:~/Work/playground$ cat review-raw-data.csv 
"a","b","c"
"1","2","3"
"4","5","6"
"5","6","7"
```

Now it's easy to avoid overwriting an existing file : just check if it exists before opening it:

```
import os

filename = 'review-raw-data.csv'
flag = "ab" if os.path.exists(filename) else "wb"
with open(filename, flag) as output:
   # etc
```

As a side note: you have quite a lot of duplicated code (`fieldnames` definition, opening the file and creating a `DictWriter`). You should either factor this out in a function, and/or only do this stuff once and pass the writer to `extract`.

```
def get_writer(outfile):
    fieldnames = [# etc ]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, restval='unknown', extrasaction='ignore')

def extract(data, writer):
    for review in data:
        # extraction happening...
        reviewobj = Review(title, text, helpfulscore, rating, date, user, reviewid, url)
        writer.writerow({
           'title': reviewobj.title, 'text': reviewobj.text, 
           'starRating': reviewobj.rating, 
           'helpfulScore': reviewobj.helpfulscore, 
           'date': reviewobj.date, 'user': reviewobj.user,
           'id': reviewobj.reviewid, 'url': reviewobj.url
            })

def main():
    filename = 'review-raw-data.csv'
    exists = os.path.exists(filename)
    flag = "ab" if exists else "wb"
    with open(filename) as outfile:
        writer = get_writer(outfile)
        if not exists:
            writer.writeheaders()
        for data in whereever_you_get_your_data_from():
             extract(data, writer)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @bruno desthuilliers, I'll definitely improve my code according to your suggestions!